# Draw Custom view or Button with diffrent style of Text

Tags: android, view

I want to put a grid of Buttons or view  in my Android mobile UI. Each button should look like this

[image]

How I can draw such a button or View with two different style of Text.  It obvious that data

> 158.0

will keep updating from server. Please suggest me.

Comment: Why can't you simply create 2 `TextView`s with different styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
----------
Create a layout like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/dim_grey">

  <!--  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/no_trips"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_active_trips"
            android:textColor="@color/rose"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/you_online"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_greem"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/in_trip_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:minHeight="75dp"
            android:minWidth="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_car_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/in_a_trip"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDark_violet"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/offline_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/you_offline"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/go_online_to_se"
            android:textColor="@color/rose"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/go_online"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/go_online"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />-->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border"
        android:padding="16dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Coolant\ntemperature"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heat_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="150.6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:padding="2dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="F"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


    ----------
    Download custom font style and add it under "font" folder in res
    You can download digitalfont.ttf as you need

    I downloaded this font from here -> http://www.1001fonts.com

    ----------
    Then in Java file 

    TextView updatableTv;
    updatableTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heat_value);

    Typeface customTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.digital_clock);
    updatableTv.setTypeface(customTypeface);

    now update your textview with values from server
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in multiple ways, I'm using [downloadable fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts) here,

1. Add dependency in module's build.gradle file:

   `dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1'
   }`
2. Add Google's maven repository in project level build.gradle file:

   `repositories {
       google()
   }`
3. Now create xml file having multiple `TextView`, with different downloadable fonts:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tempText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:text="Coolant Temperature"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       app:fontFamily="@font/sanchez" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tempVal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:paddingTop="10dp"
       android:text="158.0"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       app:fontFamily="@font/orbitron_medium" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tempUnit"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:text="F"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       app:fontFamily="@font/sanchez" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. Select `TextView` to change its font and switch to "Design" mode
5. Select "fontFamily" option from "Attributes", click "More fonts" and select whichever font is required

[image]

[image]

For more details refer this post: [downloadable-fonts-with-support-library](https://android.jlelse.eu/downloadable-fonts-with-support-library-31ba51848655)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your answer is also helpful then why it's get down vote.?

Comment: May be someone didn't understood your question and my answer to it. So down voted for both! :P